# ASP.NET UpdateProgress height

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have an `UpdateProgress` in my ASP.NET Project. This `UpdateProgress` needs to have the dynamic height of the content within `UpdatePanel`. I tried doing this with JQuery script so it gives also the right height to the `UpdateProgress`, but the script doesn't execute on each `UpdatePanel` trigger.

What is not clear for me: 
On each `UpdatePanel` trigger, are the scripts in the head of html executed everytime? Because my script for equal height is set there and it executes only ones when I open the website.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this. The following must be in the Page_Load method to let the equalHeight JQuery method be executed each time the updatepanel trigger button is clicked.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(upnlGuichet, this.GetType(), "equalHeight", "equalHeight($('.InternalItemMainGuichet'));", true);
```

Here some explanation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier with some pieces of code.

Maybe this can help: the update panel mechanism in ASP.net replaces all markup within the update panel. So if your triggers are in the update panel and you bind events on them, after the refresh the binding will be lost.

You would have to re-bind events after each request ended (you can detect this using the PageRequestManager javascript class provided in the Microsoft Ajax Framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx)

d.